# Pattern to check String start from $ or #$ in java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex. how can we use regex to identify string start with $ or #$.

Input - $asdfsadfsdaf , #$rtryrtyrtutrrt

Thanks,
Manan

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you grab a tutorial on regex and read about escaping special characters?

Comment: `if (str.startsWith("$") || str.startsWith("#$")) { ... }` would do too.

Comment: you can use `boolean m = string.matches("^#?\\$.*$");`

Answer (score 0):

Can use Java **Pattern & Matcher** classes

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\$|\\#\\$)\\w+");
```

References : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html